# Need help understanding logic behind limit proof based on epsilon-delta limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I just started Calculus and am making my way through limits. They make sense to me and the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ Definition of a Limit is also clear (I think).

However, I'm having trouble groking this example:

[image: Example 8 from section 1.2, textbook is Calculus v10e by Ron Larson and Bruce Edwards]

I get that I want to get the left side of the $\epsilon$ inequality in the format of the $\delta$ inequality.

So I have:

$$
0 < |x-2| < \delta
$$

and I have:

$$
\\ |x^2 - 4| < \epsilon
\\ |x-2||x+2| < \epsilon
$$

Now we have to do something about the $|x+2|$ term on the left side. This is where I'm having trouble following along.

*"For all x in the interval $(1,3)$, $x + 2 < 5$ and thus $|x + 2| < 5$."* I understand what they're saying, but where does the $(1,3)$ interval come from? I see that it's $c\pm1$, but that seems arbitrary. Based on this arbitrary interval we get the inequality $|x + 2| < 5$. If I had picked an interval for $c\pm2$ of $(0,4)$ than I'd get an inequality of $|x+2| < 6$. It looks like based on this interval, they continued the problem like this:

$$
\\|x+2| < 5
\\|x-2|*5<\epsilon
\\|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{5} = \delta \therefore
\\|x-2||x+2|<(\frac{\epsilon}{5})(5) = \epsilon
$$

But if I had used a different interval, say $(0,4)$, then I'd be using $6$ everywhere instead of $5$, right?

*"So, letting $\delta$ be the minimum of $\epsilon / 5$ and $1$"*: I don't get what they're saying here at all.

Can $\delta$ ultimately be put into terms of $\epsilon$ via a single function, or do are we choosing a function just so that it satisfies the limit definition?

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Adriano gave a great answer below.  I'll rephrase.  We can control the $|x+2|$ term by considering a restriction like $\delta\le 1$, which is the same thing as restricting to the interval $(1,3)$. With this initial restriction in play, we see that we can control the rest of the expression as long as $\delta$ is less than $\epsilon/5$.  But we want to make sure that we're controlling both parts at the same time.  That's where the minimum comes in - it guarantees that $\delta$ is both smaller than $1$ (so $|x+2|$ is small) and smaller than $\epsilon/5$ (so $|x-2|$ is small).

Comment: Josh, thanks for that extra bit of clarification. It made sense out of Adriano's answer for me, namely where the 1 in the minimum came from. I *think* I get it now, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; the choice of making the radius $1$ to get an open interval of $(1,3)$ was indeed arbitrary. As you pointed out, we could have picked a radius of $2$ instead and then changed $5$ to $6$ instead.

By letting $\delta = \min\{\epsilon/5, 1\}$, we gain two pieces of information. Namely, if $|x - 2| < \delta$, then we know that $|x - 2| < \delta \leq \epsilon/5$ and $|x - 2| < \delta \leq 1$. The last inequality implies that $x \in (1,3)$ so that $|x + 2| < 5$, which was important for bounding our absolute value term. This strategy of defining $\delta$ as the minimum of two terms is a powerful technique that allows us to gain extra facts in our proof.

Comment: Adriano, thanks for your answer! I'm closer to understanding, but not quite there yet. I can see where the term $\epsilon / 5$ came from, but where did the term $1$ in $min\{\epsilon / 5, 1\}$ come from? Did we pick $1$ arbitrarily?

Comment: Yes, the $1$ was picked arbitrarily. It's possible to use other numbers instead. $1$ is a nice, small, positive round number that people tend to like using in these types of proofs.

Comment: Ok, together with Josh's answer, I think I get it now. Will have to chew it over some more but I think I'm basically there. To handle the term $|x+2|$ we restrict ourselves to looking at $\delta \le 1$ (like you said, nice small number), in which case $x \in (1,3)$. Under that restriction, $|x-2| < \epsilon / 5$. To control both terms, we chose to set $\delta = min\{\epsilon/5,1\}$. That sound about right?

Comment: Yep! We need to control two terms. To control $|x + 2|$, we make sure that $\delta \leq 1$ so that $|x + 2| < 5$. To control $|x - 2|$, we make sure that $\delta \leq \epsilon/5$ so that $|x - 2|< \epsilon/5$. To ensure that $\delta \leq 1$ and $\delta \leq \epsilon/5$ are both true, it suffices to let $\delta = \min\{\epsilon/5, 1\}$.